# Heroku App Boot Timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I've got a rather large, 2.3 upgraded to Rails 3 application, that's fat enough it's not making it through the 60 second startup door at Heroku, and therefore it's crashing. I've done a bunch of work to minimize load times within Gems and initializers, but there's some random process that's burning time and I'm not exactly sure what it is. I could use another set of eyes.

Here's a GIST with the config.ru, application.rb, and environment.rb and the Gemfile.

https://gist.github.com/2026140

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was due, at least in my case, to two things: 1) a lot of gems, and 2) Mongo taking a long time to initialize (big burdened database).

To fix the gems, on my local dev, I patched bundler Kernel#require statement so I could see which were taking the longest to load. Then, I tried to remove them. Barring that, I set them to :require => false and manually required them where they were needed.

Secondly, I monkey patched Mongoid so that it doesn't try to connect to the database when the app is starting. This helped dramatically with the slow boot time (removed over 10 seconds).

Comment: Ultimately, we had to write a proxy in front that binds to the port for heroku.. then, we boot the app behind it.

Comment: can you provide some pointers for the "proxy in front that binds to the port for heroku" trick? I have the same issues and reducing the app startup time is not trivial.

Comment: The article describing a proxy is http://noverloop.be/beating-herokus-60s-boot-times-with-the-cedar-stack-and-a-reverse-proxy/, but it suffers a similar limitation where the proxy doesn't bind to port until thin is started.

Answer (score 5):

Heroku's boot timeout bit me too. I read several blog posts about how to get around it and ended up automating some of the solutions into a gem.

To reduce the startup time on deploy, you can trim the gems loaded at boot time (this doesn't mean you have to trim them from the app, just boot time).

[gem_bench](https://github.com/pboling/gem_bench) evaluates which gems are likely to not be *needed* at boot time.

I have an app with about 250 gems and was able to add :require => false to about 60 of them, with dramatic effects.

https://github.com/acquaintable/gem_bench

Disclaimer: I am the author of this open source ruby gem. I wrote the gem to aid myself in solving this exact problem: the 60 second timeout on Heroku.

Comment: Great gem, thanks for writing it and posting this answer!

Answer (score 3):

The [heroku-forward](https://github.com/dblock/heroku-forward) gem will help you beat the 60s Heroku timeout.