# Heroku rails app crash error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, crash

My Ruby on Rails app works fine in development but when I pushed the latest version to Heroku I get a h10 (app crash error). Can someone help me figure out how to fix this?

```
 2014-11-01T18:28:34.715261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=dineapp.herokuapp.com request_id=886390a9-545c-4241-aa6e-f520bead8829 fwd="74.141.109.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-11-01T18:29:18.317867+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2014-11-01T18:29:18.318060+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2014-11-01T18:29:19.486593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2014-11-01T18:29:19.516985+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-11-01T18:29:21.838385+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=dineapp.herokuapp.com request_id=2b786958-7516-4828-a08b-8c8ae571143c fwd="74.141.109.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-11-01T18:29:55.921023+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=dineapp.herokuapp.com request_id=91fd085d-f1fc-417c-9134-e0c4ea05cddd fwd="74.141.109.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-11-01T18:29:56.395060+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dineapp.herokuapp.com request_id=a969e27b-7723-4ce0-8459-c568f7ac6eab fwd="74.141.109.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-11-01T18:29:57.190074+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=dineapp.herokuapp.com request_id=c8e0f31a-fc53-462b-b32b-a6526d007408 fwd="74.141.109.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-11-01T18:29:57.441240+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dineapp.herokuapp.com request_id=ddb2731b-b47f-4699-8bbf-50fd6fcc2229 fwd="74.141.109.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-11-01T18:30:39.921818+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=dineapp.herokuapp.com request_id=8047c2a4-d4de-464c-a97a-74af40142338 fwd="74.141.109.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-11-01T18:30:40.139866+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dineapp.herokuapp.com request_id=5d2e429d-36de-414c-94ea-85a94e97d868 fwd="74.141.109.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-11-01T18:31:49.564643+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=dineapp.herokuapp.com request_id=320ac9a2-e04c-4a94-a498-7f5e97ec033d fwd="74.141.109.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-11-01T18:31:49.716703+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dineapp.herokuapp.com request_id=9b4ec9b0-5c43-4911-8ea7-e0e86aafcfc1 fwd="74.141.109.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677417/heroku-app-boot-timeout

Comment: Boot timeouts are often caused by having lots of gems. You could try using this gem to beat the heroku timeout with a proxy: https://github.com/dblock/heroku-forward

Comment: I have 15 gems is that a lot? I didn't add any gems between deployments and the last deployment worked.